# Polymer components don't encapsulate javascript

Tags: namespaces, polymer, global, encapsulation, polymer-1.0

I know that encapsulation of javascript is not part of the web component W3C spec but, what are some strategies for avoiding global namespace pollution with Polymer?

For example, if I include `<script src="./jquery.js"></script>` in my Polymer component then `$` leaks into the the host page's window object. This is very problematic for me as I am using Polymer in a chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way might be to make a `jquery-api.html` like this:

```
<script src="[path.to]jquery.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
  // make local $
  var $ = window.$;
  // kill globals
  $.noConflict(true);
  // make $ available via custom-element registry
  Polymer({
    is: 'jquery-api',
    get $() {
     return $;
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Then you could use it anywhere you need to like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="jquery-api.html">
<script>
(function() {
  var $ = document.createElement('jquery-api').$;
  Polymer({
    is: 'jquery-user'
    /* can use $ in here */
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Scott, I will give this a shot. My only concern is that this approach will have jQuery attached to the window object for a brief period before the noConflict is executed.

Comment: That may be true, but it's inevitable if you load jquery via script tag, otherwise you have to use a module loader of some kind.

Also, I believe it would pretty hard to observe the global. The script that calls `noConflict` is synchronously executed as soon as the script that loads `jquery` resolves. It's JavaScript, so there's probably a way (maybe override `HTMLScriptElement.prototype.onload`, maybe with MutationObservers) but I don't think it would happen by accident.

Comment: If you make a custom build of jQuery - you can completely control how it defines itself. For instance, you could make it a property the jquery-api.html custom element. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/README.md#modules.

Comment: @ScottMiles just out of curiosity, where does the format ``get name() {}`` on a javascript object come from? (specifically in reference to your ``get $()`` Is it unique to Polymer? I would have expected it to be something like ``get: function(something) {}``

Comment: EcmaScript 5.1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get